# Is there a way to detect all typescript files with hardcoded strings that have been used instead of i18n translation?

Tags: typescript, internationalization, static-analysis

There are some developers who have left hard-coded strings as messages or field values or labels instead of using translation constants.
Is there a way (preferably a linting tool) to capture all of these instances so that they can be moved to a translations file?

Comment: You may be able to use or adapt rule `no-literal-string` from eslint-plugin-i18next: https://github.com/edvardchen/eslint-plugin-i18next#rule-no-literal-string

Comment: Are you use any specific framework as this question may have different answers depending on that context?

Comment: Using Aurelia framework with typescript code.